# What's the difference between Softmax and SoftmaxWithLoss layer in caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, softmax

While defining `prototxt` in caffe, I found sometimes we use `Softmax` as the last layer type, sometimes we use `SoftmaxWithLoss`, I know the `Softmax` layer will return the probability the input data belongs to each class, but it seems that `SoftmaxwithLoss` will also return the class probability, then what's the difference between them? or did I misunderstand the usage of the two layer types?

Answer (score 4):

While `Softmax` returns the probability of each target class given the model predictions, `SoftmaxWithLoss` not only applies the softmax operation to the predictions, but also computes the multinomial logistic loss, returned as output. This is fundamental for the training phase (without a loss there will be no gradient that can be used to update the network parameters).

See
[SoftmaxWithLossLayer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SoftmaxWithLossLayer.html)
and [Caffe Loss](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/loss.html)
for more info.